# Firestore Write Limitation Error Code

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore is currently in beta and has a Writes per second limitation.

Is there a specific Firestore Write Error Code I can check for when writing to the Firestore database?

My use-case is I require high throughput with querying possibilities. By checking for a writing error code I could retry the write at later time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code) for **Firebase Firestore Error Codes**, `FirebaseFirestoreException.Code RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` should be the error code you are looking for.